# clickable elements should hide/show related carousels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have 3 clickable elements. Each of them belong to a different carousel. So if you click one of them, only the related carousel should show. Also the clicked div should get a green border.

My code has the following problems:

- all 3 sliders are visible, but only one (default or clicked) should be displayed
- the clickable elements arent working, but why? Also they dont get the green border

```js
  $("#marketing").click(function(){
  $("#webentwicklung1").hide();
  $("#design1").hide();
  $("#marketing1").show();
  $("#marketing.fachgebiete").addClass("active1")
  $("#webentwicklung.fachgebiete").removeClass("active1");
  $("#design.fachgebiete").removeClass("active1");
 });
 $("#design").click(function(){
  $("#webentwicklung1").hide();
  $("#marketing1").hide();
  $("#design1").show();
  $("#design.fachgebiete").addClass("active1")
  $("#webentwicklung.fachgebiete").removeClass("active1");
  $("#marketing.fachgebiete").removeClass("active1");
 });
 $("#webentwicklung").click(function(){
  $("#marketing1").hide();
  $("#design1").hide();
  $("#webentwicklung1").show();
  $("#webentwicklung.fachgebiete").addClass("active1")
  $("#marketing.fachgebiete").removeClass("active1");
  $("#design.fachgebiete").removeClass("active1");
 });
  
  
  
  
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({

    interval: 4000

 });



 // handles the carousel buttons

 $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){

   var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");

   var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);

   id = parseInt(id);

   $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);

   $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');

   $(this).addClass('selected');

 });



 // when the carousel slides, auto update

 $('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {

   var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');

   id = parseInt(id)+1;

   $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');

   $('[id=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected');

 });
```

```css
.active1{
  border:3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>




<a href="#marketing1" id="marketing" >
 <div class="fachgebiete active1" style="margin:10px;width:20%;float:left;min-height: 50px;background:red;">
  </div>
 </a>
 
 <a href="#design1" id="design">
 <div class="fachgebiete" style="margin:10px;width:20%;float:left;min-height: 50px;background:yellow;">
  </div>
 </a>
 
 <a href="#webentwicklung1" id="webentwicklung">
 <div class="fachgebiete" style="margin:10px;width:20%;float:left;min-height: 50px;background:blue;">
  </div>
 </a>
 
 <br><br><br><br><br>

<div id="myCarousel marketing1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="min-height:50px;background:red;">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">abc</div>
    <div class="item">def</div>
    <div class="item">xyz</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="myCarousel design1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="min-height:50px;background:yellow;">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">hallo</div>
    <div class="item">tschüss</div>
    <div class="item">tag</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="myCarousel webentwicklung1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="min-height:50px;background:blue;">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">hier</div>
    <div class="item">jetzt</div>
    <div class="item">später</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

what am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a bit going on here that needs cleaning up, but most of it boils down to improper `id` values on your HTML and improper attempts at referencing said `id` values within your javascript.

I've provided a working CodePen below, but a quick summary of the root causes for this not working as you have it written (I also see you edited your question & removed the duplicate click handler functions - that's a good start!).

1. An `id` cannot have a space, but all 3 of your carousels do - it appears you've copy-pasted some markup and tried to add a second ID...? Either way, simply giving each carousel a unique `id` is the key to start.
2. Your jQuery-based click handlers are failing because there is no such item with the `id` values you're attempting to hide & show (e.g. `marketing1`, `design1` and `webentwicklung1`). See point #1 above.
3. The applying of the green border (via `active1` class) is failing because your selector within your click handlers is incorrect. As written, those selectors (e.g. `#marketing.fachgebiete`, `#design.fachgebiete`, & `#webentwicklung.fachgebiete`) are matching for an element with that `id` (marketing, design or webentwicklung) AND a class of `fachgebiete`. Instead you want to target the child element with that class, thus you need a space between the id selector and the class selector (e.g. `#marketing .fachgebiete`, `#design .fachgebiete`, & `#webentwicklung .fachgebiete`).
4. Also, while not a blocking issue, because of the duplicate use of `myCarousel` as an ID, the indicators to navigate the slides in each carousel (e.g. `carousel-indicators`) are not properly mapped to each carousel.
5. Also not blocking, you don't need the functions for the carousel buttons; you get those out of the box with the use of the `data-target` and `data-slide-to` attributes.

Working example here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EEwyRa

I also cleaned up the CSS & removed the inline styles (to reduce duplication of style rules).

Comment: Thank you very much for showing the problems, helped a lot :-)